# How to host multiple applications in one Istio service mesh?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, graphql, istio, hasura

I'm setting up an Istio service mesh with two services inside both running a Graphql engine. I'm planning to set them on two different subpaths. How would you set up redirection on VirtualService?

I already tried using this VirtualService config

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: hasura-1
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - hasura-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /hasura1
    route:
    - destination:
        host: hasura-1
        port:
          number: 80
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /hasura2
    route:
    - destination:
        host: hasura-2
        port:
          number: 80
```

but I keep on having error 404 whenever I try accessing these prefixes.

**EDIT:** I've updated my virtual service to incorporate **`rewrite.uri`**. Whenever I try accessing either prefixes I get redirected to `/` and it gives out an error 404. Here is my updated Gateway and VirtualService manifest.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: hasura-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use istio default controller
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: hasura-1
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - hasura-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        exact: /hasura1
    rewrite:
      uri: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: hasura-1
        port:
          number: 80
  - match:
    - uri:
        exact: /hasura2
    rewrite:
      uri: /
    route:
    - destination:
        host: hasura-2
        port:
          number: 80
---
```

Comment: Apparently, your `VirtualService` is ok.  Can you provide the manifest used to create the `hasura-gateway`? Manifests for `hasura-1` and `hasura-2` Kubernetes services would be useful too.

Comment: @eduardo-baitello I added the manifest for `hasura-gateway` in the edited post. For the manifests of `hasura-1` and `hasura-2`, I just combined `deployment.yaml` and `service.yaml` that was found in Hasura's GKE tutorial [here](https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/tree/master/install-manifests/google-cloud-k8s-sql) and removed **`type.uri`** in the service manifest.

Comment: Hi Kean. Humm...The `Gateway` looks ok. Can you simulate the request and retrieve the logs from `istio-ingress` and the containers under the `hasura-x` services? We need to know who is returning the 404.

Comment: Hi Kean. Any updates on this?

Comment: Are `hasura-1` and `hasura-2` the services in the same namespace? If not it should be fully qualified name for them in `destination` fields then (<service_name>.<namespace_name>)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On what path your Hasura's GraphQL endpoint is configured?

The way your `VirtualService` is configured, a request to your gateway will behave like this:

`my.host.com/hasura1` --> `hasura-1/hasura1`
`my.host.com/hasura1/anotherpath` --> `hasura-1/hasura1/anotherpath`
`my.host.com/hasura2` --> `hasura-2/hasura2`

**Maybe you are missing a `rewrite.uri` rule to strip the path from the request.**

e.g.: With this rule:

```
http:
- match:
  - uri:
      prefix: /hasura1
  rewrite:
    uri: /
  route:
  - destination:
      host: hasura-1
      port:
        number: 80
```

your Hasura container should receive the requests on the root path:

`my.host.com/hasura1` --> `hasura-1/`
`my.host.com/hasura1/anotherpath` --> `hasura-1/anotherpath`

Comment: You're right, I plan on configuring my GraphQL endpoints at `/hasura1` and `/hasura2`. I tried setting up **`rewrite.uri`** like this but in both prefixes I get redirected to `/` and it gives out an error 404. 

I think it was able to access the image as it redirects forward through `/console` but it stops at error 404. Instead of this:
`my.host.com/hasura1` --> `hasura-1/`
it goes through like this:
`my.host.com/hasura1` --> `my.host.com/`

I edited my post to update the virtual service and also have the gateway manifest.

Comment: Hi @Eduardo Baitello, the problem with this is that the image used for the services doesn't accept any routes other than `/console` which is why it gives out an error 404. We didn't really need to expose the other pods as a route that's why we just had one pod to serve inside the gateway. For it to access the other pods, I applied @Anna Slastnikova comment and now it works.